# WPF DataGridCellInfo Item property value for DatePicker column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In the following `WPF DataGrid`, the following code successfully returns the value of the cell in the first column of the selected row.

For the first cell, the data item [DataGridCellInfo.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Controls_DataGridCellInfo_Item) below is a TextBlock (default):

```
DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = dgEvents.SelectedCells[0]; //cell in first column in selected row
string sSubject = (cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item) as TextBlock).Text;
```

**Question**: What should be the data item `cellInfo.Item` below? The cell does have a date value but I'm getting the error: `cellInfo_1.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo_1 .Item) as DatePicker returns null`

```
DataGridCellInfo cellInfo_1 = dgEvents.SelectedCells[1]; //cell in second column in selected row
DateTime? mydatetime = (cellInfo_1.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo_1 .Item) as DatePicker).SelectedDate;
```

**Remark**: Please note that the question is about to get the new date value selected in the cell, and NOT about the old value the cell was already bound to.

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPFProject.DataGrid_control.DataGridColumnsSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataGridColumnsSample" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Birthday">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Birthday}" BorderThickness="0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You bound selecteddate to birthday. Why are you wading through ui to get the value rather than just using birthday?